# How to Call Child form under the Parent form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How to call Child frm in my MDI frm?

**this is my code**

`frmPartyOrder.Show`

Anybody solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`With frmPartyOrder
            .MdiParent = Me
            .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            .Show()
        End With`

**such as**

`Private Sub PartyOrderToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PartyOrderToolStripMenuItem.Click
        With frmPartyOrder
            .MdiParent = Me
            .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            .Show()
        End With
    End Sub`